# Laravel - hasManyThrough return only _id

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I use Laravel MongoDB package by jenssegers and Eloquent Laravel Model.

> articles :
>
> - _id (ObjectID)
> - feed_id
> - title
>
> feeds :
>
> - id
> - user_id
> - name
>
> users :
>
> - id
> - name

**hasManyThrough** in User::class model to get all articles by one user.

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Article',
        'App\Feed',
        'user_id', // Foreign key on feeds table...
        'feed_id', // Foreign key on articles table...
        '_id', // Local key on users table...
        'id' // Local key on feeds table...
    );
}
```

I get only _id (ObjectID) with this query:

```
$user = \App\Models\User::find(1);
dd($user->articles);
```

Could you help me to search the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$user->articles()->find(1);
```

In place of `find()` you can use `first()` if you want the first record and if you want all records you can use `get()`

also if you want to put constraint use `where()` rather than `find()`

```
$user->articles()->where('_id', 1)->first();
```

Comment: can you please post what sql you are getting from this query here?